# NSDictionary Searching Issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a plist (an array of dictionary's) that I am reading into an NSArray which I am using to populate a table. It's a list of people and their work location, phone number, etc. I added a UISearchBar and implemented the textDidChange method as well.

When I search by the person's last name I do see the filtered list in the table, however I don't think that I am storing the filtered results properly. I am using an NSMutable Array but I am losing the key:value pairing.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I ultimately would like to click on a filtered name and push to a detailed view controller. I believe my issue is that I am trying to capture the filtered results in an NSMutableArray but I am not certain.

I've done a lot of Googling but can't seem to put this together in my head. Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Darin

Here is the array that I am using to load the plist.

```
-(NSArray *)content
{
    if (!content){   {
        content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ophonebook" ofType:@"plist"]];
     NSSortDescriptor* nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Last" ascending:YES];
    content= [content sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];
}
return content;
}
```

Here is the UISearchBar Method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
if (searchText.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered= NO;        
} else {
    isFiltered= YES;
    filteredPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in content)
    {
        NSString *last = [dict objectForKey:@"Last"];
        NSRange lastRange = [last rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (lastRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
        [filteredPeople addObject: [dict objectForKey:@"Last"]];
        }
    }
}
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep things simple, get rid of the flags and the different arrays in your table delegate methods. Instead, have 1 array for your source data (`content`) and another array for your source data that is actually for display (call it `displayContent`).

Now, when you start up, set `displayContent = content`.

Then, when you want to filter, set `displayContent = [content filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...];` (you can convert your current loop into a simple predicate).

Finally, when you're done searching, set `displayContent = content`.

No flags. No `if`s in the table delegate methods. Simple, readable code.

p.s. your problem is:

```
[filteredPeople addObject: [dict objectForKey:@"Last"]];
```

which you should be setting to:

```
[filteredPeople addObject:dict];
```

so you have all the data instead of just the names. Though technically you could still make it work by searching for the last name in your `content`.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. I was starring right at the problem the entire time and didn't see it. Going to circle back now and clean things up as you suggested.